# Что за ошибка в CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake

The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

D:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe

is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

Как исправить?

Comment: похоже, что у Вас не установлен компилятор или clion+cmake ошиблись

Comment: компилятор есть

Comment: в указанном месте и он "запускаемый"?

Comment: проверил на другом ide, код запускается

Comment: попробуйте задать вручную `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  "D:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe")`

Comment: Можно еще проверить path на наличие пути к g++. Проверить просто: открыть командную строку и набрать g++ --version - и посмотреть, сработает или нет.

Comment: При конфигурировании через диалог в самом clion попробуйте использовать левый слеш `\\` в путях.

Comment: переустановил компилятор так как показано на сайте jet brains, все заработало